# Grid full of textboxes, c#, XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, savestate

for start i have to say, when i'm not so good in english, so i'm sorry for my faults and grammar. 
I have easy timetable created from lot of text boxes, that are in group grid. I have one buttom, that serving to add some text into textboxes. User will add some text into texbox, will click on button (Create) and will create the complete timetable, what he need. 
And there is a problem. I could save all of input manually in method SaveState like this: `e.PageState["something"] = gui_Something.Text;` , but i have 3 grids where is 40 textboxes... I need some way to save it all in one method, or something like that. It looks like field, but it is not. In field i can do something like:

```
int[] field = new int[5];
        int some = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < field.Length; i++)
        {
            field[i] = some;
            e.PageState["Something" + i] = gui_poznamky.Text;
        }
```

but my grid full of textboxes is not field xD

Can someone help me please? I'm beginner, i started with programing short time ago, so sometimes i need some help.
Thank for all answers and again i'm sorry for my english (:

Comment: Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Or at least learn WPF. In WPF, we manipulate data, not UI controls. Instead of manually creating 40 `TextBox`es in `Grid` containers, you should have created a custom class to hold your data and then `Bind` it to a collection control's `ItemsSource` property to display it. Then, by adding a simple `DataTemplate`, you could have let WPF generate your UI for you. Finally, to save it all, you should take a look at the [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: @Sheridan that's what I'm talking about

Comment: I know @HighCore, but I'm guessing that this dude didn't. ;)

Comment: For first i have say, i don't have any experience and i learn alone for myself, i don't have any teacher, that say me how it working, or what i should do,or that exist something like MVVM, i heard word "MVVM" for first time now. I thank you for some new stuffs, what i should learn, i will do it, but it is my FIRST project and i wanna to complete it like this. Is there some "easy" way to do it, or i should delete it and star over..?

Comment: @GrowSing yes you should delete everything and start all over. Post a screenshot of what you're trying to do and we can tell you the right way to do it in WPF. BTW, I'm also a self-learning person, and I don't have any teachers either, but I strive to create clean and beautiful code all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to iterate though all the controls in the grid, and then do some fancy work to find where each textboxs' data should be saved to...

```
foreach (Control childCtrl in MainGrid.Children)
{
    if (childCtrl is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox Txtbox = (TextBox)childCtrl;
        Console.WriteLine("Found Textbox: " + Txtbox.Name);
    }
}
```